# Whats safest way to tell if decryption was successful?

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, ssl

I'm making a C program that uses GTK3 (best documentation ever) and OpenSSL (worst documentation ever) to simply encrypt/decrypt a file using a password. The encryption and decryption functions are both working, however if I enter the wrong password in the decryption phase, the file becomes corrupt (obviously). So I need a way for the decryptor  to detect if it's job was successful. Here are my solutions so far:

- AFTER encrypting, prepend a check-sum (sha1/sha256) of the original data to the file. So the decryptor can validate the original checksum and decrypted data's checksum.
- BEFORE encrypting, prepend a constant value (ie "CHECK STRING") to the file, and if the decryptor see's that the constant value was successfully decrypted, it can assume the entire file was too.

Can the unencrypted checksum be cross-analysed with the encrypted data in order to speed a brute force?

Could the encrypted constant value, *who's unencrypted value is known by the attacker*, reveal to the attacker a limited number of passwords that could encrypt the constant in that manner?

I hope this makes sense, I hate being esoteric.

Comment: `Can the unencrypted checksum be cross-analysed with the encrypted data in order to speed a brute force?` -- No.

Comment: `Could the encrypted constant value, who's unencrypted value is known by the attacker, reveal to the attacker a limited number of passwords that could encrypt the constant in that manner?` -- No.

Comment: Since you're talking about password based encryption, I want to note that you should not use a password directly as key. You need to use an expensive, salted password based key derivation function, such as PBKDF2, scrypt, bcrypt or Argon2 to derive a master key from the password.

Comment: I'd consider using LibSodium over OpenSSL.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I am using PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC.

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for crypto.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - your "no" answers assume there are no flaws in the encryption algorithm that might be exploitable with the addition of extra information.  While this may be the case, it's worth noting that cryptosystems have been designed in the past using approaches like these under the assumption that the cipher is secure, but have later been broken *because* of the extra redundancy (Enigma is the best known, of course... it was broken largely due to redundancy added by repeating a part of the message to ensure reception).

Comment: @PeriataBreatta: Yes, that's exactly right, though if your encryption algorithm is flawed, I would suggest that you have larger problems than the security of a checksum.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Unfortunately, history teaches us that all encryption algorithms are flawed, we just don't know yet in which way. History also teaches us, that sometimes somebedy *does* know, but doesn't tell anyone!

Comment: More of a question re using openssl to encrypt files: Since openssl's typically used for public key cryptography, permutation lengths are typically small to help keep execution times short. But for personal file encryption, time's not usually much of an issue. When I programmed up something for file encryption, I read the cleartext file in random block sizes between 2048 and 8192 bytes, 16384 and 65536 bits, and then randomly permuted the entire block of bits (random number seeds and pre-pumping derived from key). So is that much harder to attack, like I naively supposed, or what?

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar one well-written post on just this question is ["The Cryptographic Doom Principle"](https://moxie.org/blog/the-cryptographic-doom-principle/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using *authenticated encryption*. Its main purpose is that an attacker manipulating the ciphertext can't change the message without getting detected. But it will also reject incorrect keys.

You can either:

- Use an existing authenticated encryption algorithm, like AES-GCM, AES-CCM or XSalsa20Poly1305.
- Build one from encryption and a MAC using the [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac) construction.

  A MAC is similar to a hash, but keyed. You can only compute its output if you know the key.

Other constructions, like the ones you mention in the question are not secure when combined with common encryption algorithms like AES in CBC mode. The best known weakness is the [padding oracle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack) against unauthenticated CBC mode, but similar attacks apply to many such ad-hoc constructions.

If you want you can store a value derived from the master key (e.g. using HKDF) in the header. That can help distinguish between an incorrect key and a corrupted/truncated file.

Comment: Based on my question, it's apparent that I don't know what a MAC is. (I do now after some research). But for future readers, could you please elaborate what a MAC is and how one is created? Or perhaps explain the process of AES-GCM in detail? Thanks!

Comment: This is *extremely* important. It's trivial to modify a ciphertext in a way that produces predictable changes in the plaintext. Encryption doesn't provide integrity. You *must* have some mechanism that assures you the ciphertext hasn't been tampered with before you even try to decrypt it.

Answer (score 1):

I think, your approach of appending or prepending the checksum would be a more solid approach than, using a magic check string.

Reason - You cannot be completely sure that a garbage sequence generated by decryptor when using a wrong password will not contain the magic string.Though the probability might be low. It's possible to run out of luck.

Comment: You can't be sure that a decryption with an incorrect key won't produce data that coincidentally hashes to the same value, either.  If the check string has a similar length to the hash, the probabilities will be about the same.  In reality, neither will happen.

Answer (score -2):

I would say that any input file needs to be verified and cannot just be trusted. For example if you have an input file that is supposed to be a JPEG file, something in your code needs to check this and turn it into an image safely or fail safely, with no attack possible to put some unexpected data into the fail.

If you do that, then there is no need to check whether the file was correctly decrypted - the result of decryption would be a file that is supposed to be a JPEG file in this example, and most likely isn't if the password was wrong. If you properly check the contents of the file, then you will find that it cannot be turned into an image, and that is all you need to know.

Comment: Sounds like the answer with the 4 down votes.

Comment: A crypto program doesn't and shouldn't know what kind of file it decrypts. The user deleting the ciphertext after successful decryption isn't unlikely. Without proper integrity checks the user might only realize later that some of their files are corrupted (e.g. because they encrypted the important files using a different password).

Comment: Also if you process files manipulated by an attacker, this will likely lead to decryption oracles, like the famous padding oracle.

Answer (score -6):

Rather than trying to check the decryption. Why not pass the file to something that can read it. ie an API or application. If it failed decryption, the software won't be able to read it and should generate an error.

Comment: Well the file itself could be ANYTHING. Like a word doc, CSV, a spaghetti recipe, there would be no catch-all. It could even be an already encrypted file.